# Data analytics and statistics generation tool

Tags: data-analysis, statistics, analytics

I am looking for a data analytics component that has a UI in which we can define several rules and that can generate alerts based on these rules. Let me explain by example.

Please note that these examples are just that, they explain what I'm looking for but the tool should also allow us to define more similar and possibly more complex scenario's.

## Examples

### **Rule-based alerts**

We have a battery that we want to monitor. This battery has a temperature sensor attached. Whenever the temperature of the battery changes, we receive a datapoint. Today we define a rule in the system that sends us a notification when the temperature exceeds 35°C. Fast forward a few months and summer's here. Temperature exceeds 35° almost daily and we realize it's because of outside temperatures. Now we only want to receive a notification when the battery temperature exceeds 35°C AND outside temperature is lower than 30°C. 
Now we also want to receive a notification when battery temperature exceeds 40°C.

### **Schedule-based alerts**

Every week we want to receive a notification telling us how many times the battery has been recharged.

### **Statistics generation**

When we charge our battery we want to keep the duration for each charge value (1-100%) so we can determine how long it took the battery to fully charge at each stage of the charge cycle.

Calculate the average number of chargecycles each week.

Calculate the sum of all alerts per battery

---

## Background Information

I'm a senior programmer myself and I can surely build these things in the long run but I do not intend to invent the wheel again. If there are tools/plugins/components out there that can help me in this endeavour that would be really helpful!

Tech we're using is ASP.Net MVC + API, SQL Server, SAAS infrastructure, MQTT, C#.